# django get latest for each group, group by foreign key

Tags: django, count, group-by

Assume I have something like these models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Sale(models.Model):
  product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
  sale_date = models.DateField()
```

I want to get the latest sale **for each product**. Latest means the latest sale_date. Also, in the same query I want to get the number of products sold for each product.

In SQL terms, I need to group by product_id, to count the number of sales for each product (which is the length of each group). And maybe also to order by date (in each group as well) to get only the latest product sale.

With django ORM I realized I need to somehow use `annotate()` and maybe in combination with `values()`. But I still haven't figured how.

Assume I have this **products** table:

```
| id |   name    |    
===================
| 1  | Book      |  
| 2  | Telephone |
```

And this **sales** table:

```
| id | product_id | sale_date |
=================================
| 1  |      1     | 05-02-2015 |
| 2  |      2     | 04-02-2015 |
| 3  |      2     | 03-02-2015 |
| 4  |      1     | 06-02-2015 |
| 5  |      1     | 01-02-2015 |
```

I want to get output like:

```
| product_id |    name   | sale_date  | num_sales |
====================================================
|     1      | Book      | 06-02-2015 |     3     |
|     2      | Telephone | 04-02-2015 |     2     |
```

Since 06-02-2015 is the latest sale date for product_id=1 (Book), and 04-02-2015 is the latest date for product_id=2 (Telephone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Count, Max
query = Product.objects.annotate(num_sales=Count('sale'))
query = query.annotate(latest_sale_date=Max('sale__sale_date'))
for prod in query.all():
    print (prod.pk, prod.name, prod.latest_sale_date, prod.num_sales)
```

You will get output like:

```
(1, u'Book', datetime.date(2015, 6, 2), 3)
(2, u'Telephone', datetime.date(2015, 4, 2), 2)
```

akin to your expected output in the question. Note that whatever kwarg you pass to annotate becomes an attribute on the query result.

Comment: Thanks. It does work. But I would like to understand a few things. I know annotate() creates a new attribute for the product object. But how can you use functions like Count()? You used a parameter which is not a column in product model ('sale'), so I'm confused.  Second, is the call to all() at the end of the query is important ?

Comment: I tested this with the models as posted in your question on a fresh testing app in Django 1.7. I could be wrong, but I believe 'sale' there is just part of Django automatically populating the FK relationships for you, and it just lowercases the class name to generate it. I don't think `all` is strictly necessary because QuerySet objects are iterable, but I have been writing too much SQLAlchemy lately. I don't think it hurts to have it there.

Comment: When I test the query generated by viewing the connection.queries variable, I see a query with a group by clause by two columns. I think it is an inefficient query ?